# Using jquery priceformat plugin on focusout

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jquery price format](http://jquerypriceformat.com/) plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.euro').live('focusout', function(){
        $('.euro').priceFormat({
             prefix: '',
             centsSeparator: ',',
             thousandsSeparator: '.'
         });
    });
});
```

but this code works right only the first time, I try to insert a number. When the field loses focus, the price is formatted. If I then try to edit the price, the price is formatted every time I hit a key (and not, when the field loses focus).

Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option didn't exist, so I added it. [Here's my modification.](https://gist.github.com/4144660)